# Latent Class Analysis in R - Log Likelihood, Sample adjusted BIC, Entropy

Tags: r, statistics

I am working with Latent Class Analysis in R. Currently, I am trying to code different models with different classes (from 1-6) in order to determine the best class to use based on AIC/BIC metrics. I am using poLCA in order to create the models with each respective class.

One challenge that I am faced with is how to display the Log Likelihood, Sample adjusted BIC, and Entropy for each poLCA model. It seemed that when I tried the regular functions (for example the logLik or loglikelihood function), it doesn't work because of the way the arguments are defined - in my case I have models that I am creating.

Does anyone know how to get the values for Log Likelihood, Sample adjusted BIC, and Entropy for each poLCA model in R? Any help would be appreciated!